# Java Spring JPA - Empty foreign key when using postman

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

So I'm new to Java Spring development, I'm trying to make an application that has an OneToMany relationship, where one user has more than one address.

These are the classes:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<>();
```

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String street;
    private String number;
    private String neighborhood;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
```

So when I'm seeding before running and doing this, it works perfectly and does exactly what I expect it to:

```
        User user1 = new User("Anderson", "anderson@gmail.com", "123456789");
        userRepository.save(user1);
        Address address1 = new Address("Rua João", "997", "Teste", "São Paulo", "São Paulo", user1);
        Address address2 = new Address("Rua João", "123", "Pedrita", "Itaituba", "Pará", user1);
        addressRepository.save(address1);
        addressRepository.save(address2);
```

When I check the MYSQL database, the column user_id has the id of user1, just as I expect.

But when I try to use Postman to send the following JSON:

```
{
    "name": "Anderson Ribeiro",
    "email": "anderson@gmail.com",
    "password": "123456789",
    "addresses": [{
        "street" : "Rua João",
        "number" : "997",
        "neighborhood" : "Teste",
        "city" : "São Paulo",
        "state" : "São Paulo"
    }]
}
```

When I check the user_id column in the entity address it comes back empty, not like the one from the seeding. Why is that? I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

when you create user1 the field id is empty,when you save it in database the repository return user with new id you most reinitialize user1 after saving in database

try this:

```
 User user1 = new User("Anderson", "anderson@gmail.com", "123456789");
 user1= userRepository.save(user1);
```

Comment: When I use the seeding it works, I just put it as an example to show it.

The bigger thing is that when I use postman it doesnt. It doesnt put the user_id with the id of the user. It probably has to do with UserService or something like that. But I don't know where the mistake is, every example that I see just works.